# Cisco ASA: Why does static NAT block access through VPN?

Tags: cisco-asa, nat, cisco-anyconnect

**TL/DR**

I set up a static nat rule, so that I can use my public internet IP address to directly ssh into a dedicated machine on the inside network. As a result I cannot ssh into the dedicated machine anymore, when connected through AnyConnect VPN. Why? How do I fix this?

**Long story:**

I have an ASA 5512-X which I use to terminate AnyConnect VPN sessions. This has been working very well. People use AnyConnect to connect to the ASA, the get IP addresses from the specially assigned IP pool and they can access everything I put in the access-lists.

Now, I have this idea to directly forward port 22 to a dedicated machine in my network (I only have inside and outside interfaces), so that I can SSH into my public IP address and end up on the dedicated machine, without the requirement for a VPN connection.

The setup seemed simple enough:

```
object network MyEndpoint
    host 10.0.0.1
    nat (inside, outside) static interface service tcp ssh ssh
access-list from_outside_inside extended permit tcp any object MyEndpoint eq ssh
access-group from_outside_inside in interface outside
```

and it actually works. Now I can

```
ssh ssh.mydomain.com
```

and actually get a ssh session on my dedicated machine. However, this success comes at the cost that `ssh 10.0.0.1` does not work anymore when I am connected to my ASA/network through AnyConnect as it used to, before I set up static NAT.

I can deterministically control the ASA's behaviour:

When I **don't have** the `nat (inside,outside)` line in my configuration,

- `ssh 10.0.0.1` works but
- `ssh ssh.mydomain.com` does not work.

When I **have** the `nat (inside,outside)` rule as part of the configuration, it is the other way round:

- `ssh ssh.mydomain.com` works but
- `ssh 10.0.0.1` does not work.

To investigate I set up a capture on the ASA

```
capture MyEndpoint type raw-data interface inside
capture MyEndpoint type raw-data interface outside
capture MyEndpoint match tcp host 10.0.0.1 any
```

When I first connect via AnyConnect and then try to `ssh 10.0.0.1`, the capture doesn't show/capture anything, as long as the `nat (inside,outside)` rule is active. Also, my SSH connect attempts never reach the server.

Clearly the ASA is eating the connection requests originating from AnyConnect-connected endpoints, when the `nat` rule is active.

At first I thought I require some addition to the access-list, but I couldn't make it work that way. On which interface does VPN traffic enter the ASA anyway? outside or inside? I suppose in this case doesn't matter, because I am using a wildcard (`any`) for the source, which, in my oppinion, includes VPN traffic as well.

Then I thought the ASA would always apply the nat, which means the packet carrying the SYN-ACK would be natted to my outside IP which breaks the connection, as I am connecting from a private VPN address, not the Internet. But the SYNs never get to the server, hence there are no SYN-ACKs.

I spent all day warpping my head around the "new" `nat` command. When I do a `show nat` on my ASA I get

```
Auto NAT Policies (Section 2)
1 (inside) to (outside) source static MyEndpoint interface   service tcp ssh ssh 
    translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 0
```

As far as I got today this only does a source address translation for leaving traffic. I have no idea, how/why this implies a destination address translation for traffic originating from the Internet arriving at the ASA. Can anybody explain to me why the ASA is behaving this way?

### Edit 1: `packet-tracer`

Reading on through the documentations I came accross the ASA command `packet-tracer`. When I do

```
packet-tracer input inside tcp 10.100.0.2 31337 10.0.0.1 22
```

The ASA tells me a flow would be created and the packet accepted. When I do

```
packet-tracer input outside tcp 10.100.0.2 31337 10.0.0.1 22
```

I get

```
Phase: 6
Type: WEBVPN-SVC
Subtype: in
Result: DROP
Config:
Additional Information:

Result:
input-interface: outside
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: inside
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
```

So I guess this is some implicitly wanted behaviour, except if you are me.

### Edit 2: Searching for hairpins

I found some articles which eventually pointed me to [this promissing one](http://packetpushers.net/cisco-asa-8-38-4-hairpinning-nat-configuration/) which held the information I might need a nat rule along the lines of

```
nat (outside,outside) \
    source static \
        client_vpn_pool client_vpn_pool \
    destination static \
        remote_office_net remote_office_net
```

but it didn't work. I have a network object for my vpn client subnet and a network object for the subnet of 10.0.0.1. Adapting the template above did not yield the expected result.

When my `nat (inside,outside)` rule is in place, SSH does not work, but I can ping 10.0.0.1 just fine. When I add a `nat (outside,ouside)` rule as suggested by the article, the ping stops working. I also tried versions of the outside-ouside rule with network objects for the specific host and just the range of the `ip local pool` used for vpn clients. They all just make the ping stop.

### Edit 3: Never mind

It's working now. I literally didn't change anything. I just went to bed. I guess there was some internal state in the ASA that caused this behaviour and it timed out while I was asleep.

There is still the thing that when I use `packet-tracer input [inside|outside] tcp <my vpn ip> 31337 10.0.0.1 22` packet-tracer always says the packet would be dropped.

When I put `packet-tracer input inside` it fails at:

```
Phase: 6
Type: WEBVPN-SVC
Subtype: in
Result: DROP
Config:
Additional Information:

[...]
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
```

and when I put `packet-tracer input outside` it fails at:

```
Phase: 6
Type: NAT
Subtype: rpf-check
Result: DROP
Config:
object network MyEndpoint
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp ssh ssh 
Additional Information:

[...]
Drop-reason: (acl-drop) Flow is denied by configured rule
```

Yet, as of today, ping and SSH to/from my VPN-connected Laptop to MyEndpoint (a.k.a. 10.0.0.1) works like a charm. How does this ASA thing work???

Comment: Hi, can you go online in Chat? I have the Same ASA and it would be nice to talk about it, but not in this Thread because this is offtopic ;-) Would be very nice !

Comment: Is it? I was wondering if Superuser might have been the better place, but there we mostly discuss operating systems and this site has so many questions about ASAs ... I would like to talk about it, but I really can't. May I message you in a couple of days?

Comment: No, your post is completely correct. I mean chatting in a question is offtopic  ;-)
Yes you can message me - if you click on chat, I'll send you the data where you can find me and we can nerd talk about ASA 5512-X ;-)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: "_It's working now. I literally didn't change anything. I just went to bed. I guess there was some internal state in the ASA that caused this behaviour and it timed out while I was asleep._" Please post this as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin Even though nothing depends on it anymore. I am still looking for an explanation for what happened. I am only guessing what might have been the problem.

Comment: Well all we could do is speculate of guess, which is off-topic here. We will never be able to give you the explanation unless we had the full configuration and test results of logs and debugs.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly you can't access the inside interface of your ASA via SSH when connected via VPN?  Have you tried issuing the following command on the ASA:

management-access inside

If your VPN tunnel terminates on one interface, but you want to manage the ASA by accessing a different interface, you need to identify that interface as a management-access interface.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with accessing the ASA. When connected via VPN, I cannot ssh into the Linux server (let's call him Rudolph) that is part of my inside network and I set up the static NAT for. Everything else works great. I can ssh into Rudolph from any other computer on the inside network. I can ssh into Rudolph from the Internet. But I cannot ssh into Rudolph when connected via VPN. However, I can ping Rudolph when connected via VPN. I also have `management-access inside` set.

Comment: @user1129682, it sounds like you just need to allow SSH on the VPN. Just modify the ASA configuration to allow SSH from the tunnel interface to the inside interface.

Comment: @RonMaupin what is the tunnel interface? (pointers to doc are fine for me)

Comment: @user1129682, That is what you created for your VPN on the ASA.

Comment: @RonMaupin I didn't. I found the box in its current state and nobody is willing to even claim that the people who set it up even ever existed. But apparently the ASA is in productive use ... Do you mean the interface that webvpn is enabled on? I have `enabled outside` and `enabled inside`. Also, it is working now (see Edit 3) without any further configuration.

Comment: @user1129682, it sounds like you really don't have the skills for this. If it is working, you need to create an answer and accept it, otherwise the question will keep popping up forever, looking for an answer to a solved problem.

Comment: @RonMaupin You are correct, I don't have the skills for this, yet. I only picked up the problem(s) after it became clear that I may not get anybody to fix it for me. However, the question is mainly looking for "why does it show this behaviour". Don't you think somebody might elaborate eventually?

Comment: @user1129682 You do know that you can add an answer yourself that you can then mark as the accepted answer? Please do so.

Comment: @Marki yes, I do. I am sort of active on other se branches. Yet, answering my own questions feels odd and wrong in many ways. Most of all I don't want to get close to appreciate myself by helping myself to reputation by answering my own questions. This feels like the most narcissistic thing in the world

Answer (score 1):

Please be informed that while accessing web based SSL VPN, the NAT and PAT are restricted in CISCO ASA. Also, the traffic flow must be specified using bi-directional ACLs, by allowing return connections from a lower security host to a higher security host even if there is already an established connection from the higher level host to the lower level host (Not stateful anymore).

*Hope this is the reason for your configured NAT didn't work.*

The command "sysopt connection permit-vpn" is used in the ASA to allow the VPN traffic regardless of access-lists (exempted policy by allowing entire VPN traffic), however you can use the VPN filters and policies for restricting the traffic.

*Assuming the command is active on your firewall and the dns-server value attribute is not properly configured on your VPN policies.*

Glad to see that it worked for you without any changes.